# The "mostly code" warning should say "this post" instead of "your post" when editing someone else's post

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, wording, warning

While editing someone's post on Stack Overflow, I came across this message when OP's post was mostly code:

[image]

> It looks like **your post** is mostly code; please add some more details.

But.. this isn't *my* post.. Shouldn't it be *"*this post*"* (or some other pronoun) rather than *"*your post*"* ? It should only show *"*your post*"* for the OP but not for other people editing it.

Could the error message be changed to say "this post" when editing someone else's post?

Answer (score 10):

It's been over a year, so I'd like to post an update.

---

The wording of the error message in the question is still the same, but there is another variation of that error message which has the same issue:

[image]

> Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of **your** question as code).

Here, the use of "your" is not appropriate since the question I'm editing is not mine, but the OP's. It should be changed to either

> "[formatted] all of **OP's** question [as code]"

or

> "[formatted] **the entire question** [as code]".

Comment: Why not the passive? "Check that the [all of the] question has not been incorrectly formatted as code."